# How to make image size 'liquid' when I use flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I Have 4 flex boxes(divs) with a img and text inside of each one, I need these divs(with their content) **resize when I shrink the navigator**, so I tried 100% in width/height of images and divs but it results in larger images than the originals and a weird way to resize when I shrink the navigator.

Here is the relevant code:

```css
#features {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#features div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#features img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#features h2 {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section id="features" class="section">
  <div>
    <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/feature_01_zpsriojptqd.png" />
    <h2>Quick Turnarounds</h2> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/feature_02_zpscbrrxxka.png" />
    <h2>Free Samples</h2> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/feature_03_zpsynab7yod.png" />
    <h2>High Quality</h2> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/feature_04_zpsskjkfque.png" />
    <h2>Easy To Order</h2> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the images to grow, use `max-width` and `max-height` instead of `height` and `height`.

```css
#features img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

An to allow the flex items to shrink, use

```css
#features div {
  flex: 1; /* Distribute widths equally */
  min-width: 0; /* Ignore contents */
}
```

```css
#features {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#features div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}
#features img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
#features h2 {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section id="features" class="section">
  <div>
    <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/feature_01_zpsriojptqd.png" />
    <h2>Quick Turnarounds</h2> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/feature_02_zpscbrrxxka.png" />
    <h2>Free Samples</h2> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/feature_03_zpsynab7yod.png" />
    <h2>High Quality</h2> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/feature_04_zpsskjkfque.png" />
    <h2>Easy To Order</h2> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It works, but when I shrink the navigator It results in a strange stair form of scale (?) here is an [image](http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/Tiefnuker/img_percentage_100_shrinking_navigator_zpsuev5t7tj.jpg) to explain it better.

Comment: @GhostOrder I see. That's because the images have slightly different ratios but the flex items are equally wide. Then some images begin shrinking before others.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Oriol, are there some way to make the images shrink together? I tried setting the same size for all the images but the problem persist.

Comment: @GhostOrder Then you want to size the flex items only according to the images, but the headers interfere. Then take them out-of-flow: `#features div { flex: auto; min-width: 0; position: relative } #features h2 { position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0 }`

Comment: Oh I see, now it looks great, just one thing, how can I make the images also reduce in size when I reduce the navigator size? Because now the  images are just moving closer to each other when I shrink the navigator, and it was what I wanted, but also I need the images reduce their size gradually according to navigation size. Is this possible?

Comment: Do youu still have max-height and max-width?

Comment: Yes, I did some changes I think , but here is my [code](http://codepen.io/GhostOrder/pen/reKBjV), sorry for the late response.